# Student visitor travelling to Canada via UK

Tags: uk, transit

I am a British National and my sister has come on a visitor visa to visit me from India. My Nephew(my sister's son) has received his study visa from a Canadian university, he has an indian passport. He want's to visit and stay with us for a week first and then travel to Canada from UK. Is there a concept of extended transit visitor visa for UK?

As per https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa the max allocated time in UK is 48 hrs, so I think he won't be eligible for this one as he want's to stay for a week.

If he cannot get a transit visa does he need to apply for a family visitor visa separately? In that case would their be any issue as my sister is already on a visitor visa?

Answer (score 5):

A 7-day visit is clearly not what a transit visa is for.  It seems pretty obvious to me that your nephew needs to apply for a visitor visa.

There is no longer any such thing as a family visitor visa; it has been superseded by the [UK Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview).

I don't know how your sister's visa status might affect the decision.  I'd think that, as with most visa applications, it mostly comes down to convincing the visa officers that he will leave the UK when he says, and not cause trouble while he's there.

Comment: As part of the requested verification docs, if my nephew submits the offer letter from Canadian University for the course do you think that would be a  enough to convince the visa officers?

Comment: @tintin: I don't know.